# Get the inserted row via trigger Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, return, auto-increment

I have a trigger that gets a sequence number to put into my id column when insert a Row, the question is, how easily retun the new inserted row as resultSet.

```
create or replace trigger trg_Dependencia_id
  before insert on DEPENDENCIA
    for each row
  begin
   select DEPENDENCIA_id_seq.nextval
  into :new.id 
   from dual;
  end;
```

Comment: Where do you want the result set, within the trigger?

Comment: I want to get it as a result, like a query.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, Triggers does not return any value. Also, triggers are not for this issues.

Maybe, you can insert your nextval a temp table after insert your table(DEPENDENCIA.DEPENDENCIA_id). Then you can handle it with a function.